# django-celery-beat not creating tables

Tags: python, django, celery, celerybeat, djcelery

I've installed django-celery-beat via:

```
pip install django-celery-beat
```

Installed the app on my django project

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
'django_celery_beat',
...
 ]
```

ran migration via

```
python manage.py migrate django-celery-beat
```

I don't get any error message, and I can go to my django admin site and I see the Periodic Task section with Crontab,Intervals, Periodic Tasks, and Solar events sections. However when I click into any of them I get a message about the table not existing.

```
(1146, "Table 'mydatabase.django_celery_beat_periodtask' doesn't exist")
```

I've checked my mysql database and in fact there are no tables.

Any idea of how to force the creation of the tables?

Answer (score 1):

It seems a certain version present on PyPI does not contain the migrations. Someone placed [a similar issue/question on the repository's issue tracker](https://github.com/celery/django-celery-beat/issues/115) but it should have been fixed by now.

Anyway, you could try:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

then

```
python manage.py migrate
```

however, I would be cautious using this in production.

**Note**: It seems there are more reports of this kind of problems related to version `1.1.0`, on the issue tracker.

Answer (score 1):

Check if `django_migrations` table has `django_celery_beat` rows:

```sql
SELECT * FROM django_migrations;
```

Then, delete all `django_celery_beat` rows:

```sql
DELETE FROM django_migrations WHERE app = 'django_celery_beat';
```